# Stubbing functions with Sinon and Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, sinon

I have some file `mainFile` that uses a method `helperMethod`, which is a method that returns a Promise in a file `helperFile`. How do I stub what gets returned from `helperMethod`?

Here's what I have so far -

helperFile:

```js
export function helperMethod() {return a Promise}
module.exports.helperMethod = helperMethod;
```

mainFile:

```js
import helperMethod from helperFile;

methodInMainFile() {console.log(helperMethod);}
```

mainFileTest:

```js
import methodInMainFile from mainFile;
import * as utils from helperFile;

sinon
  .stub(utils, 'helperMethod')
  .returns(Promise.resolve(madeUpResponse));
methodInMainFile();
```

The above piece of code prints `Promise { undefined }`. How do I get it to print `Promise { madeUpResponse }`? I don't think helperMethod is actually getting called (as it shouldn't be) since I logged something there and it never shows.

Answer (score 0):

`madeUpResponse` is not defined.

You have to define `madeUpResponse`

```
import methodInMainFile from mainFile;
import * as utils from helperFile;

const madeUpResponse = 'a string';

sinon
  .stub(utils, 'helperMethod')
  .returns(Promise.resolve(madeUpResponse));
methodInMainFile();
```

Comment: I did define `madeUpResponse`, just didn't think it was necessary to show in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially assigning the helperMethod to its own variable via import, so stubbing the method on the exports object doesn't modify the original function in mainFile. The below code should work:

mainFile:

```
import * as utils from './helperFile'

methodInMainFile() {console.log(utils.helperMethod)}
```